# Unable to run powershell script remotely leading to test agent deployment failures in Azure

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, tfs, winrm

I am having a setup where I need to run automation script from a test agent. But the build step fails
with the following message

```
connecting to remote server DevBox02 failed with the following error message 
: The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the 
service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and 
documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or
WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the 
destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more 
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'. For troubleshooting
```

But when I analysed the test agent machine, I am getting the messsage that WinRM service is already running

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Not sure why I am getting this message when I am able to see WinRM Service is up and running

I have also configured the firewall exception .

Please help me in pointing what I am missing. Thanks a lot

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using vNext build? At which step this issue occurs? Can you share your build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRM/Remote Powershell service isn't configured correctly, try to reconfigure the service by following the steps here: [How to Run PowerShell Commands on Remote Computers](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/).

Comment: Thanks  a lot Eddie.