# tfs 2015 (vNext) build task: unable to Run powershell script on remote machine ( win 7)

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, powershell-remoting

Here is the simple tfs powershell build task, i couldn't make it work, trying to run the script on windows 7 machine.

[image: TFS build task]

i am getting the below error:

> 2017-11-11T21:46:00.4972350Z ##[error]Connecting to remote server
>   ryhel-d8x7frd failed with the following error message : The client
>   cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify
>   that the service on the destination is running and is accepting
>   requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management
>   service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the
>   destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
>   destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm
>   quickconfig". For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. For more info please refer to
>   http://aka.ms/powershellontargetmachinesreadme

i referred the [Same question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427715/unable-to-run-powershell-script-remotely-leading-to-test-agent-deployment-failur/47243296#47243296) , but i have no clue how to overcome this error from build task. any help would be appreciated ? Thanks.

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you taken? What have you tried that hasn't worked? This is a very broad problem with many possible causes and it's useful to know what you've already tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: Hi, I tried the [powershell instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) in the end i can not connect to remote computer, Test-WsMan COMPUTER .   also upgraded the ps version to 4. still no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PowerShell on Target Machines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines) task uses Windows Remote Management (WinRM) to access on-premises physical computers or virtual computers.

Based on the error message, generally WinRM/Remote Powershell service isn't configured correctly will cause that issue. So just try to reconfigure the service.

You can **Test the Connection** with the command `Test-WsMan COMPUTER` first for the target machine, build task of course will be failed to connect to the remote server if the service is not avaiable.

Following the step in this article to configure the WinRM: [WinRM configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm)

Also make sure WinRM service is started : `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. for the remote machine, it shows                                            'WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this computer.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.'               you mention the article, can you send me the ink please ?

Comment: @chandu Sorry for the bad link, updated the link, It's available now. I suggest you clean/rollback all before settings, then reconfig the service again following the steps.

Comment: Hi,  tried following the link, but unfortunatly the PS script not working for me. The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At C:\Users\username.fi\Downloads\ConfigureWinRM.ps1:131 char:19.

Comment: @chandu How did you download the PS script? copy the text then save as .ps file? I guess you saved the .html file instead of saving the code, please click the file then go to RAW and then download the site, or directly navigate to [vsts-rm-documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-documentation) --> Clone or download --> Download Zip

Comment: Thanks a lot, now able to run the script, but certificate creation part from the script  still fails.for win 7 machine. But its working fine on 8.1 machine.Once again thanks a lot for the help !!  .